# How to apply EditorConfig style to all files including files without extensions?

Tags: intellij-idea, netbeans, editorconfig

I introduced a *.editorconfig* file to my maven project with a following section:

```
[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

When I format the whole project in IntelliJ IDEA or NetBeans IDE I see that all files except those without extensions were formatted correctly. Why files without a file extension, for example *Jenkinsfile*, were not formatted?

Is it a problem with an EditorConfig [wildcard pattern](https://editorconfig.org/#file-format-details)

```
# every file?
[*]
```

or the IDEs?

Comment: Does IDE recognize these files as the editable text files?

Comment: How do I check it? I can see them in the IDEs, yes. I even select a file individually, select option to format the selected file, but still no luck.
See NetBeans IDE example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U8W4.png).

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA will not reformat Text files as they lack the formatter support. Not sure about NetBeans. If you associate them with some other file type that supports formatting, it should work.